# How to catch exception from non-throwing functions?

Tags: swift, exception

Sorry if the question is silly for you. I need to catch ***overflow*** exception from power function. I cannot use

```
do {
   try pow(3, 100)
}
catch {
   .....
}
```

Xcode shows warning that `pow` doesn't have `throws`. If I remove word `try` from code, then Xcode shows warning that catch is unreachable.

Any idea what can be used?

Comment: I don't think `pow` can throw anything, even in the Objective-C sense. If the result is too big you just get infinities. How about checking for infinities instead?

Comment: @Sweeper please advice in what place? Before running pow() I don't know that it will overflow.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `pow(5, 50)` gives `88817841970012523233890533447265625`, and `pow(3, 100)` gives `515377520732011331036461129765621272700000000000`, assuming you are calling the `Decimal` overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use error handling for a function that doesn't throw so any combination of `try` or `do/catch` will not work

What you can do in this case is to check if the function returns a valid number like

```
let value = pow(3, 1000)

if value.isNaN {
    //throw error or other error handling
}
```

Comment: 'Value of type 'Decimal' has no member 'isNan''

Answer (score 1):

You can convert pow to a throwing function if you prefer:

```
enum NumericError: Error {
    case notANumber
    case infiniteNumber
}

func throwingPow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) throws -> Decimal {
    let v = pow(x, y)
    if v.isInfinite {
        throw NumericError.infiniteNumber
    }
    if v.isNaN {
        throw NumericError.notANumber
    }
    
    return v
}

do {
   try throwingPow(3, 100)
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

This isn't meant to be all possible exceptions, just an example. Making it a throwing function helps with the ergonomics at the call site if you want to force the caller to have to consider all these odd cases as errors.

You can get NaN and infinite value from pow, for example:

```
let i = pow(Float.infinity, 1)
i.isNaN // false
i.isInfinite // true


let n = pow((0 / 0), 1)
n.isNaN // true
n.isInfinite // false
```

Comment: Do you know in what cases pow's  isNaN is true and when isInfinite is true? In my case isNaN returned true with large power. I wonder when isInfinite may become true.

Comment: I don't know all the rules for when pow will return NaN or Infinite but they are possible - updated answer with examples